# Cannot setup a cron job on Cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

Trying to add a cron job on Cpanel to run every 5 minutes. I added this to the command input (removed personal details from the url)

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/my_name/public_html/staging/the_web_site/wp-content/themes/my_child_theme/functions.php updateproducts
```

Then on the `functions.php`, I have this:

```
if (!empty($argv[1])) {
    switch ($argv[1]) {
        case "updateproducts":
            update_products(); 
            break;
    }
}
```

The `update_products()` function runs without any error manually if I trigger it with a button on admin page. But, no matter what I do on the cronjob tab, it doesn't run.

Any idea?

```
function update_products() {
   global $wpdb;
   $groups = get_groups_from_cron_jobs(100);
   foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
       $name = $group->group_name;
       $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}products WHERE name='%s'", $name);
       $products = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
       if ( !empty($products) ){
           $post_id = get_post_id_from_products($products);
           //if there isn't a parent_id then create a new product
           if ( !$post_id && $name != '' ) {
               $post_id = create_a_new_product($name);
           }
           // make sure that all products will have now a parent_id
           add_parent_id_on_products($name, $post_id);
           insert_product_attributes($post_id, $products);
           insert_product_variations($post_id, $products);
           delete_group_from_cron_jobs($name);
       }

   }
}
```

Edit: Based on the answers/comments, I made extra research and found that I can load the $wpdb on any script. What I did is this:

```
if (!empty($argv[1])) {
    switch ($argv[1]) {
        case "updateproducts":
            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            require( $path . '/staging/the_web_site/wp-load.php' );
            update_products(); 
            break;
    }
}
```

However, I still get the error on email:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Are you positive it isn't running at all? Can you check your server logs to see if there are any errors being generated from the cron job?

Comment: I added an email to receive the output and removed the -quite mode. I get a `Status: 500 Internal Server Error`. Which is weird since I can run it manually

Comment: Can you post your `update_products` function?

Comment: @CGriffin Done. But as I said, if I add the function on a click event on a form, it runs and I get the desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's some misunderstanding about how inter-operable the web environment and console environment are here.

In short, your function expects WordPress to exist. It expects that the user has accessed the function through the WordPress application, and that global variables such as `$wpdb` exist (among other things). If you access this function via the admin page, then this is all true, and the function works.

But if you access this function via the console (command line), none of this is true. WordPress does *not* exist within the context of that request. `global $wpdb` does not exist, because the function has not been accessed through WordPress, but through a direct command.

If you want this function to work on the command line, you will need to rewrite it to work within that environment. Which means no WordPress-specific helpers or functionalities at all.

Alternatively, you can use `WordPress Crons`, which are not true Cron jobs, but instead run whenever the site is accessed (within their defined time range). So if you have a cron that *must* run every five minutes, but you will not reliably have a new visitor every few minutes, these will not suit your needs, but they are an option.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-view-and-control-wordpress-cron-jobs/

Comment: You need to get some more detailed errors. Are there actual error logs you can access? Just a 500 error is not enough information.

Comment: On Cpanel, the errors option doesn't show anything related and the raw_access files show only the 500 error without extra info

Comment: Do you have access to the console? Can you manually run the command and see what it outputs? Can you drop some `var_dumps` in the function and see what _those_ output? You need to identify what the bug is before you can fix it.

Comment: I chose your answer as the best. You helped me found out the issues and finally fix it. It was a matter of wrong paths. I added a few var_dump here and there and found the wrong paths.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find the problem!